# Dynamic set of ngrx entities using @ngrx/entity

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Is it possible to have a dynamic set of entities using @ngrx/entity?  If so, how is it done?  If not, what is the best practice for handling this situation?

**Example**

I have dynamic list of contracts I receive from the back-end.  Under each contract I have a table of transactions that I load one by one as they are viewed.  I would like to use @ngrx/entity for the line-items on this table, but because it's dynamic I don't know how to define them.  here is a design:

[image]

The only solution I can think of is to only have one entity adapter and replace the table rows each time an accordion opens. I would enforce only one open at a time. I would also have to copy off the entities when one closes so I wouldn't lose data already loaded.

The other option I can think of without using @ngrx/entity and use the same pattern to have the contract entities and then under each of those line-item entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with dynamic entities in this context.
I would have 2 entities: `ParentEntities`, `LineEntities`.

You start with loading `ParentEntities` after you expand a row you can fetch the `LineEntities` and start populating the state. 
With selectors, you can combine parent entities with their line entities. With this data, you can render your view.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about it wrong.  By dynamic I was thinking there had to be a variable set of entities and ids for each table.